# Não consigo mandar SMS para meu Email pelo meu app Android

Tags: android

Sou novo como programador Android, tenho pesquisado em varias fontes de pesquisa de como mandar SMS para meu email, peguei um exemplo de um livro na internet, porém ao executar ele não gerou nenhum erro e somente informou uma mensagem em tela que não conseguir entender devido a minha falta de experiência.

essa foi as mensagens em LogCat

```
11-26 18:09:43.721: I/Choreographer(790): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 18:09:43.971: D/gralloc_goldfish(790): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-26 18:10:22.246: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 87K, 9% free 2556K/2788K, paused 27ms, total 30ms
11-26 18:10:22.476: I/Choreographer(790): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

essa foi a tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse aqui é meu projeto

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Send Email" />

</LinearLayout>

package br.com.google.sms2;

import com.example.sms2.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class EmailsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] to = { "tecnico100@gmail.com" };
        String[] cc = { "tekaband@gmail.com" };
        sendEmail(to, cc, "hello", "helo meu amigo");

    }

    private void sendEmail(String[] emailAddresses, String[] carbonCopies,
            String subject, String message) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        String[] to = emailAddresses;
        String[] cc = carbonCopies;
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"));

    }

}




<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sms2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="br.com.google.sms2.EmailsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Você está a usar o emulador. Verifique se o emulador tem uma aplicação de email. Além disso tem também de configurar uma conta de email.

Comment: me dê uma referencia para configurar o emulador para mandar email, porque eu sei por onde começar, até para mim pesquisa fica difícil porque eu não sei como pesquisa também, e me mostrar também configuração de email, seria Telnet? meu telnet está instalado e ativado e meu emulador já recebe mensagem pelo telnet.

Comment: Veja [isto](http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/06/how-to-send-email-from-android-emulator.html)